# Assign more cores to virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

I have a Intel i5 processor (4 core), why am i not able to assign more than 2 cores to Centos 7 64 Bit in Virtualbox?

Is there a limitation or i may be missing something ?

[image]

Comment: That slider appears to go to 4 cores. Does it not let you save if you slide it to 4?

Comment: What is the host OS? Is virtalization enabled in the BIOS? Does you specific CPU model support virtualization?

Comment: @jordanm You are right, i was concerned because when i moved it beyond green part Virtualbox said invalid settings however on saving the setting they appear to allocate 4 CPU ( Confirmed from the OS too ) Please mark your suggestion as the answer.